# I'm unable to perform virtual method invocation

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

This is my code:

```
class base1
{

}
class der1 extends base1
{
 public static void main(String []args)
 {
  base1 b=new der1();
  b.showTest();
 }
 public void showTest()
 {
 System.out.println("Hello i am a derive class");
 }

}
```

Comment: Please, name your classes with uppercase it should be: `Base1` and `Der1` also is preferred to place opening brace in the same line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it will not compile.

you need `showTest()` in base class also to make it compilable

base1 b=new der1();
b.showTest();

here `b` is the reference of `base` , you need `showTest()` in `base` at compile time it wil check for `showTest()` in `base` and at run time due to

`base1 b=new der1();`
it will invoke `der1`'s version of `showTest()`

**Also See**

- [Polymorphism](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html)

Answer (score 1):

The method `showTest()`  is defined in the subclass.  To be able to use it you have to:

1.- Declare it in the base class

```
class base1 {
     public void showTest(){
     }
}
```

Or 
2.- Declare `b` as  `der1`

```
public static void main( String [] args ) { 
    der 1 b = new der1();
    ...
```